# Data not valid on $http requst in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, server

Im new to angular js i want to post a url to server
this is my code

**Index.html**

```html
<html ng-app="signupApp">

<head>
  <title>ServicePrice Signup</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="centerwrap">
    <div class="Signup" ng-controller="SignupController">
      <!-- <form action="signin()"> -->
      <h2>Signup</h2>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" ng-model="email">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" ng-model="password">
      <input type="submit" class="button" ng-click="signup()">
    </div>
    <!-- </form> -->
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**controller.js**

```js
 var signupApp = angular.module('signupApp', [])
 var site = "http://devhosting.wiredelta.in:9009";
 signupApp.controller('SignupController', function($scope, $http) {

   $scope.signup = function() {

     var data = {
       email: $scope.email,
       password: $scope.password
     };
     $http({
       url: site + '/company/signup',
       method: "POST",
       data: data,
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       }
     }).success(function(data) {
       console.log(data);

     }).error(function(res) {

       console.log(res);

     });
   }
 });
```

how can clear this error and get response from server
both email and password reaches server but is says "bad request" all the time

**error in console**

```js
POST http: //devhosting.wiredelta.in:9009/company/signup 400 (Bad Request)
  controller.js: 24 Object {
    error: Object
  }
error: Objectmessage: "Data is not valid"
type: "BadRequestError"
__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Please provide console logs.There can be possibility that the webservice that you are calling need some other parameters.There can be possibilty that that Content-Type that you are sending is different then the respective web service want and there can be possibility that application accept params via GET instead of POST

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Angular does not automatically encode the parameters in a formpost, like in jQuery.

You have to do this yourself, just like you have to add the header `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` yourself, like you already did.

If you include jQuery you can do it like this: `$.param(data)`

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found it as yang li told we need to convert data , so i used this

```js
transformRequest: function(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for (var p in obj)
    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
  return str.join("&");
}
```